# Trying to mix a Symphonic Rock/Metal song

Tags: mixing, logic-pro

(Just to note, I am NOT just trying to show my song here. I am asking a valid question about mixing this track that others may find helpful for their productions as well.)

I'm sorry if this the wrong place to ask a question like this, but I couldn't find a stackexchange for music PRODUCTION, so it's worth a shot...

This my first pro mixing project with Apple Logic, and I've always sucked at mixing and balancing the tracks. I was wondering if you kind folks could help me make this

http://www.filedropper.com/vc

http://www.filedropper.com/vcng (WITHOUT GUITAR)

Sound more like this

http://dis-gate.net/data/2007/free0603.mp3

And maybe just share some "Gotta know these" basic mixing tips, or a place to look for them and learn from. How to pan things appropriately and such? I know it's up to the ear in the end but there's probably a common template for where to start right?

I mean until recently I didn't even know to separate different parts of instruments into different tracks (kick, snare, toms, hihats, guitar1/guitar2, etc etc) and I still don't know if I'm doing that right...I MAY have overdone it.

Currently my project looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGbwP.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh6KY.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmXS4.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYe81.png

I'm using Sennheiser EH150 headphones also, and can't currently get good monitor speakers.

I also I imported this project from Garageband if it matters.

Comment: Could you please upload the track to soundcloud and _embed_ it from there, or at least post the links in a way that can actually be used? (You may want to read the quick help on post formatting.)

Comment: Actually, this is this Stack Exchange site for music production (and also other audio and video production).  Welcome! :) I actually don't have any reason to close the question unless it's too vague. "looking for some pointers" is really hard to answer cleanly, but "I'm trying to create this effect, is there something clearly wrong with my mix?" is a lot more answerable. Make sure your question is focused on the second one.